# ternary operators for calculus class

Tags: math, ternary-operator, calculus

I was wondering about the use ternary operators outside of programming.  For example, in those pesky calculus classes that are required for a CS degree.  Could a person describe something like a hyperbolic function with a ternary operator like this:
    1/x ? 1/x : infinity;
This assumes that x is a positive float and should say that if x != 0 then the function returns 1/x, otherwise it returns infinity.  Would this circumvent the whole need for limits?

Comment: How could a notation circumvent the need for limits?

Comment: I think you meant `x ? 1/x : infinity` rather than `1/x ? 1/x : infinity`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certian as to the specific question, but yes, a ternary can answer any question posed as 'if/else' or 'if and only if, else'. Traditionally however, math is not written in a conditional format with any real flow control. 'if' and other flow control mechanisms let code execute in differant ways, but with most math, the flow is the same; just the results differ.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, any operator can be equivalently described as a function, as in `a + b = add(a,b)`; note that this is true for programming as well.  In either case, binary operators are a common way to describe functions of two arguments because they are easy to read that way.

Ternary operators are more difficult to read, and they are correspondingly less common.  But, since mathematical typography is not limited to a one-dimensional text string, many mathematical operators have large arity -- for instance, a definite integral arguably has 4 arguments (start, end, integrand, and differential).

---

To answer your second question:  no, this does not circumvent the need for limits; you could just as easily say that the alternative was `42` instead of `infinity`.

I will also mention that your `1/x` example doesn't really match the programming usage of the `?:` ternary operator anyway.  Note that `1/x` is not a boolean;  it looks like you're trying to use `?:` to handle an exception-like condition, which would be better suited to a try/catch form.

Also, when you say "This assumes that x is a positive float", how is a reader supposed to know this?  You may recall that there is mathematical notation that solves this specific problem by indicating limits from above....

Comment: I think I understand, your saying that a ternary operator would be redundant because it would be determining the value of a function based on the parameter(s) of that function when that's what the function itself is already doing.

Comment: To sum up what I meant:  1) operators are just functions written differently and math uses ternary and higher-arity operators just like computer languages do;  2) the answer to your question about limits is "no", and your example doesn't really make any sense in that context.